# VBA Multi actions(with if then inc) after IF THEN

Tags: vba, excel, action

So, I've a code that gives me in this case only my first action in a cell. 
I can't get my 2nd action working.

The code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim i As Integer

If Me.Control1.Text = "" And Me.Control2.Text = "" And Me.Control3.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Please select a name in the list"

Else

i = Me.lstMyData.ListIndex
Me.lstMyData.Selected(i) = True

     If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Database").Cells(i + 1, "I").Value = "TRUE"

     Worksheets("Database").Cells(i + 1, "J").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text

End If
```

Any idea why my 2nd action doesn't work? If I switch the actions I still got the same problem. The first one always works and the 2nd never.

Comment: Which "second action"?  What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What 's it "supposed" to do? Also the title of your question is hard to understand.

Comment: I'm not understanding the `lstMyData` lines of code - it's saying "tell me which item in the listbox is selected and then select that item".  If nothing is selected then an error occurs as `ListIndex` will be -1 and `Selected` starts at 0.  The second part of the code - I take it the _second action_ are the statements after the `Else` - will only execute if there's is a value in `Control1, 2 or 3`.  Do you have `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` somewhere which will make it look like that code hasn't executed if no items are selected.

Comment: well, to be more specific. I'm trying to make an interface for the user with a listbox. Once the user selected a name in the listbox, this same info apprears in the controlboxes.
So if nothing is selected in the listbox, you get an msgbox saying you have to select a name. This to prevent deleting information by validating empty textboxes.

Comment: The user will also get the possibility to use checkboxes and textboxes to add data to the corresponding name. 
The correct info with the correct name has been coverd by the use of 'i' the the code. 
But my problem is to get the data from the userform into my worksheet at the corresponding name.

Comment: So to solve my problem: I tried to take the same cell as the listbox (as it is the same database). So the 'i' + rownumber will define where i want the userform information to be added ==> check if the names are corresponding (userform-database).

Comment: my 2 actions i want to perform are:
1) Me.checkbox1.value = True Then Worksheets("Database").cells(i+1, "I").Value = "TRUE" 

2) Worksheets ("Database").Cells(i+1,"J").value = Me.textbox1.Text 

So the 1) is to get the true or false info from the checkbox to a specific cell. The 2) is to get the text info from the userform textbox to a specific cell as well. 

Row I is the True or False row, Row J is the textbox info

Comment: By it doesn't work i mean: If i put he code for the Checkbox first, i will get a TRUE in cells in row I. But as the code for the textbox is 2nd, No information will get in cells from row J at all.
If i turn it the other way around, so i put the code for the textbox first and then the Checkbox. I will get my textinfo in row J but nothing in Row I from the checkbox...

Comment: The listmydata: you have to think with a userform and database.